# Delivering In-App Purchase Content via Server

Tags: iphone, ios4

My iPhone app will be a free app but for some special content, users need to buy.

For example I have 4 files for free and if the user want to buy another file he has to purchase it. I am sure that I need to use Server Product Model to deliver the content.

What I want to know is: how will content be delivered to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this u got very good tutorial on  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGDGO5P95Dg

in this application tutorial show how to download files and store in our application...

may be this is useful to you..

Answer (score 0):

You have to go for in-app purchase.
This link will help you.

[In-App Purchase without using iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052128/iphone-in-app-purchase-to-sell-our-products)